# добавить в одну таблицу среднее значение из другой

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

есть 2 таблицы

movies:

```
movieId | title       | rating
--------------------------------
1       | toy story   | NULL
2       | terminator  | NULL
```

ratings:

```
movieId | rating
----------------
1       | 4
2       | 3
2       | 5
1       | 3
```

нужно добавить в `movies` столбец `rating`, где будут средние значения из таблицы `ratings`.
пробовал сделать такой запрос:

```
insert into movies(rating) 
select round(avg(rating),2) from ratings 
group by movieId
```

но добавлялось после данных:

```
movieId | title      | rating
----------------------------
1       | toy story  | NULL
2       | terminator | NULL
NULL    | NULL       | 3.5
NULL    | NULL       | 4
```

как добавить правильно? т.е. вот так:

```
movieId | title      | rating
----------------------------
1       | toy story  | 3.50
2       | terminator | 4.00
```

заранее спасибо!

Comment: для начала надо добавить столбец rating в структуру базы данных, а потом сделать update с left join по movieId и установить значение

Comment: @splash58 можете, пожалуйста, написать, а то я новичок в sql и не очень понимаю на словах. спасибо

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE movies
SET movies.value = (
    SELECT round(avg(rating),2) 
    FROM ratings
    WHERE ratings.movieId = movies.movieId
);
```